# WMF editor/converter for Linux?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, office, microsoft-office

I have some WMF file which I got from a .doc document. It has some vector graphics and some text in Arabic. I tried opening it in Inkscape, but that failed.

Is there a more robust WMF editor for Linux, or a converter into SVG or something else that's reasonably editable

Required features:

- Gratis
- If it's a converter - faithful conversion into .svg, i.e. I can trust the SVG to show exactly what the WMF does when opened in MS Office (provided the appropriate fonts are available).
- Robust against undocumented (mis-)features of WMFs generated by Microsoft tools
- Runs on x86_64-based Linux systems

Desired features:

- Libre
- Actively maintained
- Runs on multiple platforms

Comment: did you take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035588/how-to-convert-wmf-files-to-svg-files)? [wmf2svg](https://github.com/hidekatsu-izuno/wmf2svg) might be the solution. Otherwise, if there's no working solution, you might ask the Inkscape team for help?

Comment: @myrdd: I just have, I downloaded the repo, but when I try to build it with `mvn package` I get a nearly-empty package :-(